# What does shell: /bin/bash -e {0} mean in bash shell output from a github action worker?

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, github-actions

Because git commits exit with non-zero code when there are no changes to be committed, this causes the github action to fail. To overcome that I try to check if there are any changes before committing like the following -

```
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    echo "changes_exist=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
else
    echo "changes_exist=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
fi
```

GitHub then shows this to me below it -
`shell: /bin/bash -e {0}`

Googling this does not seem to yield anything. Any idea what that means?

Exact output of the runner -

```
Run if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
  if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
      echo "changes_exist=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  else
      echo "changes_exist=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  fi
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64/lib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{0}` is replaced by the value of the `run` element from your workflow definition

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell

You can also change the error handling if you use e.g.

```
  run: echo "Test"
  shell: bash {0}
```

This would result in calling `bash echo "Test"` instead of `bash -e echo "Test"`.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#exit-codes-and-error-action-preference

Comment: Since I am getting `{0}` that means that the bash command it runs above successfully ran and exited with a code of 0. Had it failed then the output would have been ```shell: /bin/bash -e {1}``` - am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: No, `{0}` is not the exit code, it's a placeholder for an argument. Here it will be replaced with the shell code to be executed. The log will also print `{0}`.

Comment: Okay, so basically that whole line just means that it is running a shell code. Nothing more than that? (I am sorry...I am kinda confused at this point)

Comment: Exactly, the important information is the exact shell that is used and the arguments like `-e` because they influence the behavior regarding e.g. error handling.