# Why shell for loop doesn't work in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have an action that is supposed to run a benchmark multiple times, however the step containing the loop ends after first execution of a command inside the loop.

I could reproduce the issue with a simpler case - with plain shell commands below

```yaml
name: ci-pipeline
on: ["push"]
jobs:
  benchmark:
    steps:
      - name: run a loop
        run: |
          for run in {1..3}; do
            date;sleep 1;
          done
```

When I run the for loop locally (everything below pipe above), I get:

```
Fri Jun 24 13:25:57 CEST 2022
Fri Jun 24 13:25:58 CEST 2022
Fri Jun 24 13:25:59 CEST 2022
```

However, in GitHub Action, when using:

```
  for run in {1..3}; do
    date;sleep 1;
  done
  shell: sh -e {0}
  env:
    PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL: ***url1 ***url2
```

The return I get is only:

```
Fri Jun 24 10:15:40 UTC 2022
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be related to the `shell` field you used.

*You can check the available values you can use with the `shell` field [on the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell)*

I made a test on a Github actions workflow using `shell: bash`:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: run a loop
        run: |
          for run in {1..3}; do
            date;sleep 1;
          done
        shell: bash
```

And it returned as expected:

```
Fri Jun 24 12:17:42 UTC 2022
Fri Jun 24 12:17:43 UTC 2022
Fri Jun 24 12:17:44 UTC 2022
```

If you want to have a look:

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester42.yml)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7041375134?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: It makes sense that used shell would be a suspect. In my case, I see in the output `sh -e {0}` was used - do you know what {0} means here?

Comment: I can confirm adding `shell: bash` fixed it`.

Comment: There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283887/what-does-shell-bin-bash-e-0-mean-in-bash-shell-output-from-a-github-action) about this `sh -e {0}` that can bring some insights :)